# How to decide to cuttoff frequecies of filter in case of using ADC( Flow: Analog-signal to ADC to bits to fir_filter to filtered_output)

Tags: filtering, vhdl, adc, digital-filter

1. FIR filter has to be used for removing the noise.
   I don't know the frequencies of the noise that might be adding up into the analog feedback signal I am taking.
2. My apparatus consists analog feedback signal then i am using ADC to digitize the value now I have to apply FIR filter to remove the noise, Now I am not sure which noise the noise which added up in the analog signal from the environment or some sort of noise comes there due to ADC ?
3. I have to code this in vhdl.(this part is easy I can do that).

My main problem is in deciding the frequencies.

Thanks in Advance ! 
I am tagging vhdl as some people who are working in vhdl might know about the filter.

Comment: You may have better luck with this question on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you have a look at the analog signal? If you know how it looks like and how it should look like, you can decide what to filter

Comment: Turn the question around : what frequencies do you need to preserve through the filter?

Comment: Thanks, Actually i don't know the frequencies which are present in the feedback signal So I can not decide which to preserve and which to remove. Anyway I posted the question on electronics.stackexchange.com hope I get a solution there.

Comment: Did I answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by stating the obvious: An ADC samples at a fixed rate and can not represent any frequency higher than the Nyquist frequency

**Step one:** understand aliasing, and that any frequency higher than the Nyquist will alias into your signal as noise.  Once you get this you understand that you need an anti aliasing filter in your hardware, in your analog signal path before you digitize it.  Depending on the noise requirements of the application you may implement a very complicated 4 pole filter using op-amps; the simplest is to use an RC filter.

**Step two:** setting the filter cut off.  Don't set the cutoff right at the Nyquist frequency, make sure the filter is cutting well before the nyquist (1/2x... 1/10x, depends really how clean and how much noise is present)

So now you're actually kind of over sampling your signal: The filter is cutting above your signal, and the sample rate is high enough such that the Nyquist frequency is sufficiently higher.  Over sampling is kind of extra data, that you captured with the intent of filtering further, and possibly even decimating (keeping on in N samples and throwing the rest out)

**Step three:** use a filter to further remove the noise between the initial cut off of the anti-aliasing filter and the nyquist frequency.  This is a science on it's own really, but let me start by suggesting a good decimation filter: Averaging 2 values.  It's a box-car filter of order 2, also known as a SINC filter, and can be re applied N times.  After N times it is the equivalent of an FIR using the values of the Nth row in pascal's triangle (and divided by their sum).

Again, the filter choice is a science on it's own really.  To the extreme is the decimation filters of a sigma-delta ADC.  The [CS5376A datasheet](http://www.cirrus.com/en/pubs/proDatasheet/CS5376A_F4.pdf) clearly explains what they're doing; I learn quite a bit just from reading that datasheet!